# Automatically interlink between two blogs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two different blogs. Blog nr.1 and blog nr.2

I need post nr.12 from blog nr.1 to display a link to post nr closest to 12 from blog nr.2. Automatically.

How can i make this?

Comment: What have you tried or thought about possible ways of doing it tested any of them?

Comment: Yes, i could use rss, to pull posts from other blos, but lets say I have a 20 blogs to interlink, i'll have to pull 20 feeds wich is alot:(

Comment: Are they all running on the same server?

Comment: Yes they are, same host, same IP